# How do you generate collections with a specific property (like stddev) using test.check

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, test.check

I want to use clojure's `test.check` library to generate collections that I can do some simple stats on, things like computing mean, stddev, confidence intervals and that sort of thing.

How can I generate the collections so that they have pre-determined values for these properties?

Comment: You can generate collections of random numbers and then manipulate them to have particular values, though I think it would be harder if you're targeting several properties at once.